# Electron: renderer access to main process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

The main process opens a connection to a service, to which a renderer requires access.

Is this possible?

I've tried declaring `global.thing` and `exports.thing`, and having the renderer `require('electron').remote.thing` — where thing is a function or scalar — but no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in more ways:

1) Communicate between process with ***ipc*** and ask data with ***ipcRenderer.sendSync*** function, that asks to main process and wait for a return value. 
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md

2) use exports in the right way, so:

in the main process:

```
exports.functionName = functionName;
```

in the renderer:

```
var functionName = remote.require('./main').functionName;
```

Comment: @emish89: Can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485770/access-a-function-in-main-window-from-renderer-process-in-electron?noredirect=1#comment70204002_41485770