# Access a function in main window from renderer process in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I am integrating the Skype web sdk conversation control in my application. I have

- the main process in the background
- there is a main window (a separate renderer process)
- there are chat windows (separate renderer processes) which have been opened by clicking on the main window

In the main window, I am initialising the Skype Web SDK, signing in the user and then fetching the contact list. Now when I click on a contact, it should open separate chat window and start the conversation control in this window.

The skype call in main window looks something like

```
skypeWebApi.renderConversation(containerDivReference)
```

The skypeWebApi.renderConversation function is available in main window renderer process and containerDivReference is available in the chat window renderer process

To achieve this, I Passed skypeWebApi reference to chat window renderer process. However, due to serialization, renderConversation isn't available here. So it doesn't work.

Is there any way to access this function placed within the main window renderer process?

I tried to send an event to main window with the containerDiv reference, but that didn't work either. Plus, it didn't seem like a very clean solution as there were a lot of events going to and fro.

Right now what I am trying to achieve is communication between 2 separate renderer process.

I can also restructure my code to initialise the SDK in main process and let these renderer processes (main window and chat window) call the functions in the main process

Any help?

Comment: If the SDK requires access to the DOM you have no choice but to load and run it in the renderer process.

Comment: @VadimMacagon : Can't I call the function in the main process in any way?

Comment: From your description the function expects a DOM node, you can't pass a DOM node from one process to another because it won't be serialized/deserialized properly.

Comment: It seems it'll require a total redesign then, because initialising skype sdk and signing in the user multiple times won't go well wrt licensing.

Comment: Your use of terminology is slightly confusing.. The main window, being a windows is also a renderer process. Did you mean the main process or you meant a window, which you are calling main window? It seems from what I understood so far, you are initializing the skype web sdk in a window. But as per your requirements you need to access it across windows..?