# How to access class instance in Electron from browser JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I am writing an Electron application using AngularJS for the main part of the application.  I have a class defined in the Electron main.js file

```
class SessionService {
    constructor() {
        this._isAuthenticated = false;
    }

    get isAuthenticated {
        return this._isAuthenticated;
    }

    set isAuthenticated(value) {
        this._isAuthenticated = value;
    }
}
```

and I instantiate as below

```
const sessionService = new SessionService();
```

This creates an instance of `SessionService` in the main process of the electron application and if I do `console.log(sessionService.isAuthenticated)` then I get the value output to the terminal

When I load the `index.html` file this loads in the browser and then loads up angular, etc.

I want to be able to access `sessionService` from my app.js.  This would allow me to maintain a users session details in a class instance that would survive refreshes and the like.

Is it possible to be able to access the class instance in this way and if so how can this be achieved? For example, I know how to do IPC but is there a way that one could set a variable on the window that could then be accessed from the renderer, e.g. `mainWindow.webContents.session = sessionService` then access this from JS with `window.session.isAuthenticated`

Comment: and what's wrong with IPC?

Comment: Nothing at all but if there is another way to access this or any other instance variables or static objects

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166869/electron-renderer-access-to-main-process) related?